# How to divide equal parts of grid using grid(fr) only using HTML and CSS

Tags: css

Hy friends, I want to divide a page into 5 equal parts using CSS grid property and it's doing better work but still, I am unable to understand the logic behind this. In a CSS grid system, a screen has 12fr units and here I used only 10fr units so that is what happens if I leave 2fr units or There is any other way to use all 12 units.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 2fr);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <footer class="grid">
      <div>A</div>
      <div>B</div>
      <div>C</div>
      <div>D</div>
      <div>E</div>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

> *"In a CSS grid system, a screen has 12fr units"*

No it doesn't. It has as many as you tell it to have. In your case you have told it to be 10fr wide with `grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 2fr)`

There is generally no need to use multiple values of `fr` since `grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);` will do the same thing.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}

.grid div {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<footer class="grid">
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div>D</div>
  <div>E</div>
</footer>
```

If you want a 6/12 column grid just adjust to `grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);`

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
}

.grid div {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<footer class="grid">
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div>D</div>
  <div>E</div>
</footer>
```

As you see since you only have 5 elements they take up the first 5 columns.

Comment: Thank you that's a great knowledge